# I want to create a program that checks ip address continuously

Tags: winforms, c#-5.0

I want to create a program that checks ip address continuously.

i have a code that checks ip address and port, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;   
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace WinNetworkIOCS {
     public partial class Form1 : Form {
         public Form1() {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
             DisableFields();
             DoNetworkingConnection();
         }

         private void DisableFields() {
             PortBox.Enabled = false;
             IPAddressBox.Enabled = false;
             SendMessageBox.Enabled = false;
             ConnectButton.Enabled = false;
         }

         private void EnableFields() {
             PortBox.Enabled = true;
             IPAddressBox.Enabled = true;
             SendMessageBox.Enabled = true;
             ConnectButton.Enabled = true;
         }

         private void WriteToStatusBar(string Message) {
            //EnableFields();
            ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, lblStatus, Message);
         }

         private void DoNetworkingConnection() {
            Thread MyThread = null;

            try {
               ThreadStart ThreadMethod = new ThreadStart(ConnectTo);
               MyThread = new Thread(ThreadMethod);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               WriteToStatusBar("Failed to create thread with error: " + e.Message);
               return;
            }

            try {
               MyThread.Start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               WriteToStatusBar("The thread failed to start with error: " + e.Message);
            }
       }

       private void ConnectTo() {
          string ServerName = this.IPAddressBox.Text;
          int Port = System.Convert.ToInt32(this.PortBox.Text);

          WriteToStatusBar("IP Address: " + ServerName + "Port: " + Port);
          Socket ClientSocket = null;

          try {
             // Let's connect to a listening server
             try {
                ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                WriteToStatusBar("Socket is OK...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create client Socket: " + e.Message);
            }

            IPEndPoint ServerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerName), Convert.ToInt16(Port));

            try {
                ClientSocket.Connect(ServerEndPoint);
                WriteToStatusBar("Connect() is OK...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect client Socket: " + e.Message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            WriteToStatusBar(e.Message);
            ClientSocket.Close();
            return;
        }

        // Let's create a network stream to communicate over the connected Socket.
        NetworkStream ClientNetworkStream = null;

        try {
            try {
                // Setup a network stream on the client Socket
                ClientNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(ClientSocket, true);
                WriteToStatusBar("Instantiating NetworkStream...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // We have to close the client socket here because the network
                // stream did not take ownership of the socket.
                ClientSocket.Close();
                throw new Exception("Failed to create a NetworkStream with error: " + e.Message);
            }

            StreamWriter ClientNetworkStreamWriter = null;

            try {
                // Setup a Stream Writer
                ClientNetworkStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(ClientNetworkStream);
                WriteToStatusBar("Setting up StreamWriter...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ClientNetworkStream.Close();
                throw new Exception("Failed to create a StreamWriter with error: " + e.Message);
            }

            try {
                ClientNetworkStreamWriter.Write(this.SendMessageBox.Text.ToString());
                ClientNetworkStreamWriter.Flush();
                WriteToStatusBar("We wrote " + this.SendMessageBox.Text.Length.ToString() + " character(s) to the server.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to write to client NetworkStream with error: " + e.Message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            WriteToStatusBar(e.Message);
        } finally {
            // Close the network stream once everything is done
            ClientNetworkStream.Close();
        }
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
}
```

Problem is that it does not check the ip address and port continuously.
What to add into my code to make this happen?

Comment: What is it actually doing, Andy? Does it check once? Does it fail at any point? Generate an exception?

Comment: I've tried it, but no error at all. I saw it only executed once, how do way more than once, in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that what you mean is that you wish to be able to run your program more than once, not that you wish for it to check over and over again and therefore that your problem is in fact that your program finishes the task of pinging but then never allows you to enter new information?

This is because in your function

```
private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
             DisableFields();
             DoNetworkingConnection();
         }
```

You run the function DisableFields(); and DoNetworkingConnection(); Assuming that the DoNeworkingConnection(); works and it runs the code once then your problem is that you never enable your controls again since in

```
     private void WriteToStatusBar(string Message) {
        //EnableFields();
        ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, lblStatus, Message);
     }
```

You have commented out EnableFields(); that re-enables your controls. If this is not the case and you are actually trying to make it run continuously you would have to wrap the sending part of the ConnectTo() in a while loop

```
while(true)
{
ClientNetworkStreamWriter.Write(this.SendMessageBox.Text.ToString());
                ClientNetworkStreamWriter.Flush();
                WriteToStatusBar("We wrote " + this.SendMessageBox.Text.Length.ToString() + " character(s) to the server.");
}
```

Though if this is the case please state what you are trying to achieve and you will probably get a better solution because this will quickly turn into something like a DOS attack..